# show arabic/italian/indian language in J2ME

Tags: unicode, java-me, bitmap, arabic

I created a quiz application in J2ME, I need to show unicode arabic/italian/bangla to the mobile. It works fine in nokia handsets which has multi language support. But I need to show unicode
character in those devices which does not support unicode. I need to show unicode character like opera mini.
I searched various websites and forums, but I could not found any solutions. Please help me if anyone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have take design custom font by using images of the alphabets. Follow [this](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?122363-Custom-font&p=531131#post531131) thread for the procedure.

Comment: Suggested thread does work, but I did not like the use of sequence.indexOf(ch). If you consider adding all characters from arabic/italian/indian this will leave you with a big sequence String. You can also try my approach :) http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2008/12/custom-monospaced-font.html

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the deprecated [Opera website](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/designing-with-opera-mini-in-mind/):

> International text and fonts
>
> Opera Mini supports internationalization, including the full range of character sets supported by Opera in addition to Unicode. However this is dependent on font support in the phone which commonly is limited. Bidirectional text is not supported in Opera Mini.

So it looks like boils down to font support for Indic scripts, but for your Hebrew and Arabic needs you will probably be disappointed.

*Edit:* According to a quick internet search, there is an option `use bitmap fonts for complex scripts` in `opera:config` which allows some sort of server-side rendering of complex scripts.